# Can we remove default.aspx page from deploy location?

Tags: configuration

What is the use of default.aspx page(present in deploy location) which comes with Sitecore installation?

If we remove, will it have any impact?

Sitecore: 8.2 update 3

Comment: Which Sitecore version you are on ?

Comment: Updated the description with version..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Default.aspx` in the standard install of all versions of Sitecore is nothing more than a placeholder page, it serves no purpose in the normal operation of a functioning Sitecore instance. The page itself contains no logic or is not tied to any backend code, and simple outputs the text "Default page".

The page *could* be useful to check if your IIS instance has been set up correctly, or that a 200 status code is being returned (although the `Heartbeat.aspx` is better for this purpose).

You can delete this page if you wish, but unless someone browses to `/default.aspx` directly then this page should not normally be served by the system.

Comment: Also, worth mentioning that the Heartbeat.aspx page has been broken for sometime and does not work OOTB. http://sitecorehacker.com/2017/11/22/bug-heartbeat-aspx-page-returns-500-error/

Comment: Thanks jammy kam.. always clear and concise answers...